# something about div & image rotate 360 degree by jquery

Tags: jquery, rotation

Just like the title, I want to make a image or a div rotate in my webpage.
And, I find jqueryrotate.js in google code
http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/
This author enplain how to make it work using the function in jqueryrotate.js and give some examples in jsfiddle and it looks great!
But when it turns to me, it doesn't work no matter how I try even copy the author's code, the image just keep static.
I have no idea what's wrong with it and hope someone could give some help.

The code i write just like the below:

```
<html>
<head>
<scripttype="text/javascript"src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rotation = function (){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation,
      easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
          return c*(t/d)+b;
      }
     });
    }
    rotation();

    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img style="margin:10px;"src="/arrow.png" id="img">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I try to write some code like the totura and it just doesn't work

Comment: WHAT have you tried? We can't say what you're doing wrong unless you show us what you've tried.

Comment: i post my code above ~

Answer (score 3):

Your script include in the html has a typo:

```
<scripttype="text/javascript"src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
```

rather than including a script you were including a scripttype

Answer (score 3):

Your code has some errors. Try this.

```
var rotation = function (){

$("#img").rotate({
  angle:0, 
  animateTo:360, 
  callback: rotation,
  easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
      return c*(t/d)+b;
  }
 });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
rotation();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TRQKE/

Of course, you also need to correct the script tag that Joe mentioned. And you need to include jquery itself which is not included in your code sample:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you have jquery included?

Comment: That is perfect example, how can we manipulate it with mouse? if someone want to rotate the block manually to right or left. Thanks